# How to reduce lag on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: swift, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to reproduce a UI like the popular app Vine. Right now I have multiple table cells each with a MPMOVIEPLAYER. When the user scrolls it calls the "play" method on the current view. The issue that I'm encountering is that every time the user scrolls to a new video the player will block the main thread. This will cause a noticeable stutter in scrolling. How does Vine seem to do the exact same thing but with fluid scrolling?

If you need more info please feel free to ask.

Comment: Could you post your current code for the view controller class so I can have a look at how you've got it implemented? Thanks!